# Разборка define

Tags: c++, макросы

Не могли бы вы мне прокомментировать каждое действия этого кода?

```
#define DEF_TYPENAME(type) template <> \ struct NameOf<type> {\
static const char value[];\ };\
```

Как я понимаю:

```
#define имя_макроса последовательность_символов = #define DEF_TYPENAME(type) template <>
```

Более подробный код:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct NameOf {};

#define DEF_TYPENAME(type) template <> \
struct NameOf<type> {\
    static const char value[];\
};\
const char NameOf<type>::value[] = #type;

DEF_TYPENAME(int)
DEF_TYPENAME(double)
DEF_TYPENAME(long double)
DEF_TYPENAME(float)
DEF_TYPENAME(char)
DEF_TYPENAME(long)
DEF_TYPENAME(unsigned)
DEF_TYPENAME(unsigned long)

template <typename T, typename ...types>
void printTypes(T)
{
    std::cout << NameOf<T>::value << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename ...types>
void printTypes(T, types... t)
{
    std::cout << NameOf<T>::value << ", ";
    printTypes(t...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printTypes(1,2U,3L, 4.0, 5.0L, 6UL, 'a', 8.0F);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`#define` -- обычная замена. Каждый раз, когда препроцессор ви дит запись `DEF_TYPENAME(type)` он заменяет её на

```
template <> // NameOf -- шаблонная структура, но полность специализруется тут
struct NameOf<type> {
    static const char value[];
};
const char NameOf<type>::value[] = #type;
```

То есть специализирует структуру `NameOf` для типа `type`. Задавая внутри структуры одну статическую переменную. Дальше идёт инициализация статической переменной. Почему она происходит именно так, и что такое статический член класса можно прочитать 
[тут](http://cppstudio.com/post/3298/). `#type` превратит переданную значение в строку и именно этой строкой будет инициализирована статическая переменная класса.
То есть в результате вызова `DEF_TYPENAME(int)` мы специализируем структуру NameOf и в статическую переменную `NameOf<int>::value` запишем строчку `"int"`.

Answer (score 0):

Каждое упоминание `DEF_TYPENAME(T)` разворачивается в создание типа со строковым членом данных, в который попадает переданное имя `T`. Далее функцией `printTypes` выводятся типы переданных аргументов, связанные через инстанцированный ранее шаблонный тип.